# I need to load data to my python3 program from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to load data to my python program from a file. Could you tell me what is the easiest way?

the file is user_id.txt and content is :

```
['1668938807', '8646077542', '2926881681', '634754486']
```

also what I tried but did not work is:

```
with open('user_id.txt', 'r') as f:
  data = f.readlines()
  lines = []
  for line in data: 
      content = line.split(',')
      for el in content:
        new_el = el.strip('\'')
        print(new_el)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Define "did not work"

Comment: Is the data in *exactly the format specified*, brackets, quotes, commas and all?

Comment: correct the data is in this format. I use a python function to return a list and save it to file. I want to use that same file later and import the data to my program but as a list

Comment: make a .py file and initialize into a variable, later you can just import that variable. Or save using `json.dumps` and use `json.loads` to read the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below (using the fact that the file content can be directly loaded into a list using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html))

```
import ast 
with open('user_id.txt') as f:
  lst = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
  print(lst)
```

output

```
['1668938807', '8646077542', '2926881681', '634754486']
```

Comment: This solution works perfect. I have never heard about ast. Going to read more about it

Comment: ok I will try to do that with JSON. I always thought JSON is used with Python dict.

Comment: @Etika49 It should depend on your file.  If your file is rows of lists, then this is appropriate.  I think he was probably implying, it's better to save your data in a JSON to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load numbers to array you can try this:

```
numbers = []
with open("user_id.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        stripped = ex[1:-1] #stripped bracelets
        numbers.append([ int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, num))) for num in stripped.split(",") ] )
```

Anyway you should consider using json
Hope i answered your question

Comment: agreed if you control the input file format, then I would change the data to json format and use the json module to load it.